# get all facebook groups where person is in using PHP SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using PHP SDK to query some information but when I ask for my groups:

```
$facebook->get('/me/groups');
```

It returns me only groups where I'm admin, not all groups where I'm. How may I get full list of groups where I'm ? Tkanks

Comment: `user_groups` permission has been removed with API v2.4. Now you get access to the groups the user is an admin of only (using the new `user_managed_groups` permission.)

Answer (score 0):

As CBroe commented already, you can only access groups you manage:

> the user_groups permission has been deprecated. Developers may
>   continue to use the user_managed_groups permission to access the
>   groups a person is the administrator of.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_deprecations